# Get single item from Room DB. Call the function from view model

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao, android-viewmodel

So my general question is how to call a function from view model for @Query where you have to pass something and then return something.
My simple example:

**DAO**

```
@Query ("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
fun getItemById (id: Long) : MyItem
```

**Repo**

```
fun getItemById (id: Long) : MyItem {
return itemDao.getItemById(id)
}
```

I know that it cannot and should not be done on ui thread. For inserting and deleting an item i use viewModelScope job but i cannot (maybe just don`t know how to) use it to return anything.
If i return it everywhere as LiveData, then it works just like that:

**ViewModel**

```
fun itemById(id: Long): LiveData<MyItem> {
 return itemRepo.getItemById(id)
}
```

And then i observe it in a Fragment/Activity:

```
viewModel.itemById(id).observe(this, Observer {
 // using it
})
```

The thing is, that i dont really need it to be an observable livedata. I only need to get it once, check condition and thats it.
So maybe someone could recommend how to do it, without it being a livedata. Or should i leave it a live data?

Comment: Have you tried the answer I suggested by any chance?

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for your answer. I looked into it, but it is still a livedata object, so i have to observe it. What i am looking for, is a way to call a function in a viewmodel, so i could use it in Activity/Fragment like this: val singleItem = viewModel.itemById(id)

Comment: Hi Nick, any particular reason u don't want to observe the data. If it is an asynchronous call, ideally you should be observing it. If you are not observing and reacting to the data changes on your UI, it is a sign of bad implementation. The function itemById() looks asynchronous and I would also recommend you to handle different UI states whilst your data request...e.g: Loading, Success, Error.

Comment: well... after facing a couple of new challenges, i decided to rethink my approach and ended up optimizing the whole project. So now i actually have less fragments/viewModels, less code and LiveData fits perfectly into this right now. Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the update only once, then I recommend SingleLiveEvent instead of LiveData. 
Here is the class provided by google: [Github link](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)

A blog on how to use it: [Link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)

The only drawback of SingleLiveEvent is that it can't have multiple observers.

If you don't like LiveData, you could try RxJava's *Single* [Observable]